# Angular on Docker runs but gives empty response

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile, containers

I dockerized an application.
The dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM node:14.17.3

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.json ./
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./web.config ./

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build:linux

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Then I create the build using this command:
docker build -t my_app:latest .

And finally run it with:
docker run -d -p 4234:4200 my_app:latest

If I run a terminal inside the container, and run `curl localhost:4200` I get a response back, meaning internally the server is running inside the container.

If I run in the host computer, `telnet localhost 4234` the port is open.

But, if I open the browser and connect to http://localhost:4234/ I get error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I'm out of ideas about why this can be happening

Comment: Your app probably *binds* to localhost which causes it to only accept connections from inside the container. You need to have it bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: you are correct, I added `--host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check` in my ng serve command and now it is responding. If you want to answer we can mark it as resolved. Thanks!